TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float32' has no len(). (Tracking people)
import cv2
import numpy as np
from ultralytics import YOLO
from deep_sort_realtime.deepsort_tracker import DeepSort

def count_unique_people(video_path):
    model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')  
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Error opening the video file")
        return
    
    tracker = DeepSort(max_age=30)
    unique_ids = set()
    
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        results = model(frame, classes=0)
        
        detections = []
        for result in results:
            boxes = result.boxes.xyxy.cpu().numpy()  
            scores = result.boxes.conf.cpu().numpy()  
            
            for box, score in zip(boxes, scores):
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = box[:4]
                detections.append([x1, y1, x2, y2, score])
        
        # Updating the tracker with new detections
        if len(detections) > 0:
            tracked_objects = tracker.update_tracks(np.array(detections), frame=frame)
        
            for track in tracked_objects:
                if not track.is_confirmed() or track.time_since_update > 1:
                    continue
                bbox = track.to_tlbr()
                obj_id = track.track_id
                unique_ids.add(obj_id)
            
            # Displaying frames for visualization
            for track in tracked_objects:
                if not track.is_confirmed() or track.time_since_update > 1:
                    continue
                bbox = track.to_tlbr()
                obj_id = track.track_id
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1])), (int(bbox[2]), int(bbox[3])), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                cv2.putText(frame, f'ID: {int(obj_id)}', (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]) - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
        
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
    print(f"Unique people have been discovered: {len(unique_ids)}")

# An example of using the function
video_path = 'video_2024-05-21_02-46-30.mp4'
count_unique_people(video_path)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\79246\Desktop\Recognize_test\rec.py", line 65, in <module>
    count_unique_people(video_path)
  File "c:\Users\79246\Desktop\Recognize_test\rec.py", line 36, in count_unique_people
    tracked_objects = tracker.update_tracks(np.array(detections), frame=frame)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\79246\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\deep_sort_realtime\deepsort_tracker.py", line 195, in update_tracks
    assert len(raw_detections[0][0])==4
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float32' has no len()


You are getting this error probably because len() is only for types string and list

The error is inside the library code.  This is not a helpful answer.

"len() is only for types string and list" that is false.
